# Number conversion in Python 2.7: base6 to base10

Tags: python-2.7, bitcoin, radix, dice

Searched about this and didn't find useful help. Maybe I searched wrong. Figured I might just ask here and find out more by that.

Let's say I have 99 numbers with a range from 1 - 6 made from rolling a 6 sided dice 99 times.
And I want to convert this from base6 (is this already base6 format?) to base10 in python 2.7, how would I do it? Code should be non cryptic and readable.
Automatic replacement of 6's to 0's would be good to, if needed.
It's for Bitcoin Private Key generation by the way.
The dice rolls are being entered in manually right when it asks "Enter dice rolls: "

Basicly converting 6 sided dice rolls from number range 1 - 6 -> 0 - 5 -> 0 - 9

Don't laugh, basicly what I have written now is just this:

```
import ...????
dice_input = input("Enter dice rolls: ")
dice_convert_base6_to_base10 = base10.encode(dice_input)...????
```

No idea if or what I would need to import and what to do with the dice_input. My question may sound a bit stupid to most of you, please don't judge.. Thanks a lot for every help I can get!

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in `int` function [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int).

It does conversion from `string` to `integer` types. So, you will need to get the input as a string [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

It accepts a second (optional) parameter of the base you want to assume the source comes from.

Code would end up looking something like:

```
dice_input = raw_input("Enter dice rolls: ")
dice_convert_base6_to_base10 = int(dice_input, 6)
```

To convert any `6` to `0`, then you could just use the `replace` method of the string [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Code would then be changed to something like:

```
dice_input = raw_input("Enter dice rolls: ").replace('6','0')
dice_convert_base6_to_base10 = int(dice_input, 6)
```

Not certain about if this is really the way to get the key generation you want... but, I don't think I really grokked the use-case.

Comment: First: Thanks! It's basicly connected to my other code found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114578/python-2-7-converting-bitcoin-privkey-into-wif-privkey If the other code is done I want to start by generating a random number, entering that in and let it process to a bitcoin private key. Because I want to give the script the first random number it has to work with by myself and not let it be generated by my computer. Your method resultet in: "AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'replace' if I enter the 99 numbers. Tried out your 2nd codeversion.

Comment: If I enter only the numbers 123456, it returns "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: my fault, that is what I get for answering without testing... try using the `raw_input` built-in function instead of `input`.

Comment: By the way, background info: This is the Bitcoin private key wiki: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format and this is the step by step guide how to start from dice rolls and get a Bitcoin private key: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=919430.5;imode  So you can see in more detail what I am trying to do here. Giving my script a non digital produced random number sounds more safe to me than relying on my computer generating one. The first random number is the most important, if that is not truely random, it's not safe.

Comment: raw_input works, produces no errors! By the way, raw_input was what I had used there in the beginning but changed it to input for some reason. Trying to connect this to the whole process of Privatekey generation to end up wth a WIF Private key with my code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114578/python-2-7-converting-bitcoin-privkey-into-wif-privkey now. Thank so far for now! :) Btw: Isn't there this "base10" process missing in your code line? Or am I stupid haha

Comment: In 2.7, the `raw_input` function returns a string. Alternately, `input` tries to run the input and returns the results of running it (in this case giving you an `int`). In the 3.x series of Python, they got rid of the `input` function's behavior and renamed `raw_input` to `input`.

Comment: Python will store the `int` in Base-2 (that is just how computers store numbers, for most purposes), but the default for printing out will be in Base-10.

Comment: It may be that you don't actually want base conversion, but want to do some other form of conversion....